# flatMap Not returning onCompleted

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I have created below function with chaining of multiple observables however whatever I do it does not seem to call `completed` ? it only return the following:

```
(facebookSignInAndFetchData()) -> subscribed
(facebookSignInAndFetchData()) -> Event next(())
```

even though when I `debug` the observables individually they all return `completed`

here is my chaining function

```
func facebookSignInAndFetchData() {


    observerFacebook.flatMap { (provider: FacebookProvider) in
        return provider.login()
        }.flatMap { token in
            return self.loginViewModel.rx_authenticate(token: token)
        }.flatMap {
            return self.loginViewModel.fetchProfileData()
        }.debug().subscribe(onError: { error in

            //Guard unknown ErrorType
            guard let err = error as? AuthError else {
                //Unknown error message
                self.alertHelper.presentAlert(L10n.unknown)
                return
            }

            //error message handling
            switch err {
            case .notLoggedIn:
                print("not logged in")
                break
            default:
                self.alertHelper.presentAlert(err.description)
            }

        }, onCompleted: {
            self.goToInitialController()
        }).addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)

}
```

**rx_authenticate**

```
func rx_authenticate(token: String) -> Observable<Void> {


    return Observable.create({ observer in
        let credentials = SyncCredentials.facebook(token: token)
        SyncUser.logIn(with: credentials, server: URL(string: Globals.serverURL)!, onCompletion: { user, error in

            //Error while authenticating
            guard error == nil else {
                print("error while authenticating: \(error!)")
                observer.onError(AuthError.unknown)
                return
            }

            //Error while parsing user
            guard let responseUser = user else {
                print("error while authenticating: \(error!)")
                observer.onError(AuthError.unknown)
                return
            }

            //Authenticated
            setDefaultRealmConfiguration(with: responseUser)

            //next
            observer.onNext()

            //completed
            observer.onCompleted()


        })

        return Disposables.create()
    })
}
```

**fetchProfileData**

```
func fetchProfileData() -> Observable<Void> {

     return Observable.create({ observer in

        //Fetch facebookData
        let params = ["fields" : "name, picture.width(480)"]
        let graphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params)
        graphRequest.start {
            (urlResponse, requestResult) in
            switch requestResult {
            case .failed(_):
                //Network error
                observer.onError(AuthError.noConnection)
                break
            case .success(let graphResponse):

                if let responseDictionary = graphResponse.dictionaryValue {

                    guard let identity = SyncUser.current?.identity else {
                        //User not logged in
                        observer.onError(AuthError.noUserIdentity)
                        return
                    }

                    //Name
                    let name = responseDictionary["name"] as! String

                    //Image dictionary
                    let pictureDic = responseDictionary["picture"] as! [String: Any]
                    let dataDic = pictureDic["data"] as! [String: Any]
                    let imageHeight = dataDic["height"] as! Int
                    let imageWidth = dataDic["width"] as! Int
                    let url = dataDic["url"] as! String

                    //Create Person object
                    let loggedUser = Person()
                    loggedUser.id = identity
                    loggedUser.name = name

                    //Create photo object
                    let photo = Photo()
                    photo.height = imageHeight
                    photo.width = imageWidth
                    photo.url = url

                    //Append photo object to person object
                    loggedUser.profileImage = photo

                    //Save userData
                    let realm = try! Realm()
                    try! realm.write {
                        realm.add(loggedUser, update: true)
                    }

                    //next
                    observer.onNext()

                    //completed
                    observer.onCompleted()

                } else {
                    //Could not retrieve responseData
                    observer.onError(AuthError.noResponse)
                }
            }
        }



        return Disposables.create()
    })


}
```

**observerFacebook**

```
//FacebookProvider
private lazy var observerFacebook: Observable<FacebookProvider>! = {
    self.facebookButton.rx.tap.map {

        return FacebookProvider(parentController: self)
    }
}()
```

Comment: Looks good. Can you add rx_authenticate and fetchProfileData implementations?

Comment: it is added now. thank you in advance

Comment: Can you also add definition for `observerFacebook`?

Comment: you need login function aswell? `observerFacebook` has been added

Comment: Both functions looks good - the should always complete with either completed or error. Can you check if that is correct - both observer.onCompleted are called?

Comment: not sure what you wan't me to check however i have added `observer.onCompleted()` to all observables and thats why i don't know why it is not completing with an error or completed but only `onNext`

Comment: It looks like onCompleted() in either rx_authenticate or fetchProfileData aren't called. Put breakpoints on all onCompleted() statements and double check if the are called at all

Comment: all are called...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The chain starts with calling `observerFacebook`, which returns an observable that will emit values everytime `facebookButton` is tapped.

This observable will only complete when `facebookButton` gets released, most probably when the view controller holding it is removed from screen.

The rest of the chain will `map` or `flatMap`, but never force completion as another tap will trigger the whole chain again.

The *easy* way to solve this would be to add a call to `take(1)` on `facebookButton.rx.tap`, so that the function would be defined like so:

```
private lazy var observerFacebook: Observable<FacebookProvider>! = {
    self.facebookButton.rx.tap
    .take(1)
    .map {
        return FacebookProvider(parentController: self)
    }
}()
```

Now, `observerFacebook` **will** complete after the first tap and you should see a call to `onCompleted`.

Note that you'll need to resubscribe to the chain on errors if you want to perform it again when another tap comes in.

Comment: In case anyone else lands here looking for rxjava answers, the idiom I use  is `Observable.create(s -> { s.onNext(new Object()); emitter = s; }).flatMap($ -> realObservable)`  and then `emitter.onComplete()` will propagate the `onComplete()` to the subscriber.